# Difference between .yml and .groovy files in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, github-actions

I am new to jenkins pipe line and as is very much confused between yml files and .groovy files. I came across this github repo [link](https://github.com/automate6500/github-actions-demo/blob/master/.github/workflows/pipeline.yml), where he defines all the jobs & steps in .yml file

```
name: Pipeline

on: [push]

env:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:     ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION:    ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Check
        uses: ./.github/action-check
      - name: Build
        uses: ./.github/action-build
```

In second case, I came across a private repo which has file structure containing metadata.yml and jenkinsfile.groovy

```
// metadata.yml
project:
  owner: bkch
  rwversion:
    type: plain
    file: VERSION
jenkins:
  view:
    - modules
env:
  docker-image: com/dev_env_g3_g5:1.7.1
```

and then the groovy file

```
@Library('jpsl') _

standardPipeline {
  standardNode('linux_docker') {
    stage("Build and Publish Docker image") {
      sh "./build.sh ${env.RELEASE_VERSION}"
    }
  }
}
```

I am confused that in one scenario they have defined the pipeline steps in yml file and at other place they are defined in groovy file and the coding style is different in each. Is it because one is provided by github and the other by jenkins ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

[Github help](https://help.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/migrating-from-jenkins-to-github-actions) explains key differences Jenkins and GitHub Actions / Migrating from Jenkins to GitHub Actions.. It says:

> Jenkins and GitHub Actions both allow you to create workflows that
>   automatically build, test, publish, release, and deploy code. Jenkins
>   and GitHub Actions share some similarities in workflow configuration:
>
> - Jenkins creates workflows using Declarative Pipelines, which are similar to GitHub Actions workflow files.
> - Jenkins uses stages to run a collection of steps, while GitHub Actions uses jobs to group one or more steps or individual commands.
> - Jenkins has two types of syntax for creating pipelines: Declarative Pipeline and Scripted Pipeline. GitHub Actions uses YAML to create
>     workflows and configuration files.

Comment: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)